# Online / PHP Comments Form For Non Static URL

Tags: php, facebook, comments

I'm setting up a little website as an addon to my existing site and at the moment I'm using Facebook comments, which I like because it does help to get people interacting as well as linking back to my wesbite.

If all goes well with the site I'd eventually like to give it a dedicated URL, however I know that I will lose all comments if I do this. So is there any other way to have a comments section which will keep my comments when I change the domain name:

`http://site.wesbite.com/article/0402 - http://www.newwebsite.com/article/0402`

I know that these can be built with PHP & a database but I'm looking for a slightly simpler solution.

Any help would be hugely appreciated